# Powershell -Split "<tr*>"

Tags: powershell

I am trying to split a string of html data. Example of the command I am trying to use is:

```
$foo -split "<Tr*>"
```

It doesn't do anything. I believe that the `<>` are special characters and need an escape character. I have tried *backtick* and *backslash* in front of the angle brackets, but neither is working. Any advice would be great. Thanks.

PetSerAl's advice was the way I went. I think I was trying to go towards something I was more familiar with by using the splitting method. I found a good bit of info on how to parse the html data to get what I needed.

Here is the link in case anyone else is stumped on this. https://geekeefy.wordpress.com/2017/01/24/powershell-tip-parsing-html-from-a-local-file-or-a-string/

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: "*It doesn't do anything.*" - not doing what you want isn't the same as not doing anything :P   "*I believe that the <> are special characters and need an escape character*" - easily tested.  `'a<b' -split '<'` nope, not special, works fine. Asterisk is the special character, it does not behave the same in regular expressions as it does in other pattern matching languages. Maybe `$foo -split "<Tr.*?>"` will work.

Comment: Just for completionism: You can use the string method `.split()`, which does not use `RegEx`. With that there is no need for escaping. Else, use `[regex]::excape('<Tr*>')` to let the RegEx engine escape your string,

Comment: PetSerAl's advice was the way I went. I think I was trying to go towards something I was more familiar with by using the splitting method. I found a good bit of info on how to parse the html data to get what I needed.

Here is the link in case anyone else is stumped on this. https://geekeefy.wordpress.com/2017/01/24/powershell-tip-parsing-html-from-a-local-file-or-a-string/